# Remove property key using filter()

Tags: javascript

```
var a = [{'id':1,'name':'James','age':11}];

a = a.filter(function( obj,i ) {
            //return obj != 'age';
          });
```

filter will create a new array, but how to splice away the age property key? Didn't use jquery, can't use $.grep in this case. and won't use delete because it's not really delete the key but leave an empty slot.

Comment: Use `.map` instead.. And `delete` will do...

Comment: That's an array of object(s). You are iterating through the array elements not the properties of first child of the array which is an object, i.e. you should iterate twice.

Comment: Could you add an example of the desired end product? Do you know about all the keys in the object in advance, or is that dynamic?

Comment: For reference, `delete` will [**not** leave an empty slot](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array#forEach` and `delete` operator to delete the `key`

```js
var a = [{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'James',
  'age': 11
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'James2'
}];

a.forEach(function(obj, i) {
  obj['age'] && delete obj['age'];
});
console.log(a);
```

Comment: delete will not remove the key but left an empty slot

Comment: @JamieJordan [No it doesn't](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Comment: @JamieJordan That’s only for arrays. It works properly for plain objects.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
a = [{'id':1,'name':'James','age':11}];
b = a.map(function(v, i) {
    var copy = {};
    for(key in v) {
        if(key != 'age') {
            copy[key] = v[key];
        }
    }
    return copy;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var a = [{'id':1,'name':'James','age':11}];

a = a.filter(function( obj,i ) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty('age')) {
        delete obj.age
        return obj;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please specify the final o/p you want ?